# Exchange data between Python and PHP

Tags: php, python

Is it possible to exchange data between a PHP page and a Python application? How can I implement a PHP page that reacts to a Python application?

**EDIT:**

My application is divided in 2 parts: the web backend and a Python daemon. Via the web backend I upload MP3s to my server; these MP3s are processed by my Python daemon which fetch metadata from Musicbrainz.

Now:

I need to ask the user the results of the "Python fetch" to choose the right metadata.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a Python application which checks for some MP3 metadata on online databases and I need to output its result in response to the PHP page that uploads songs on my server.

Comment: you need python call internal php code Or call as web page and pass params?

Comment: I edited the description. Now it should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Python script that takes a path in `sys.argv` or the audio data via `sys.stdin` and writes metadata to `sys.stdout`. Call it from PHP using `exec`.

Comment: It's how Unix has been working for 30 years. But now that you mentioned a daemon you'll want to connect via a socket instead of a pipe.